# Elasticsearch l1norm function score

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to find out whether l1norm function calculates score the way I think it is.

So I have this index

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_dense_vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 3
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "my_dense_vector": [3, 4, 5]
}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/2
{
  "my_dense_vector": [1, 2, 3]
}

POST my-index-000001/_refresh
```

When I execute this query:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "l1norm(params.queryVector, 'my_dense_vector')", 
        "params": {
          "queryVector": [3, 3, 3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like the scores are calculated as sum of absolute deltas, or this formula

```
ABS(X1-Y1) + ABS(X2-Y2) + ABS(X3-Y3)
```

I just want confirm if this is how the scores are calculated for `l1norm` function

Comment: in general, the lp norm is calculated as (sum (abs(xi-yi)^p))^(1/p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is how L1 distance is defined